# Cordova to read creditcard or medicare card, or go native?

Tags: cordova, cardreader

This is a Cordova related question, didn't know where else to post it.

I am researching the possibility to use Cordova to build my app. 
The only hard part is that it needs to communicate with a magnetic card reader (for credit cards or medicare cards..in essence read channel 1-3).

The customer is going to chose a card reader so in worst case if there is no SDK I probably have to build something myself to capture the card swipe.

My question is: can this be done with Cordova, can I build my own plugin that will be able record the audio signal and process that. If this is very hard, I might do decide to go native.
However, Cordova would take away building 3 versions (iOs, Android and Windows).

If i can, I will convince the customer to chose a reader that has an SDK, and then I hope I can connect Cordova with the SDK.

It is a bit of a new area for me so hence my exploratory questions.

Comment: Is there any card reader that only emulate a hardware keyboard input?  in this case you don't need any sdk in all platforms!

Comment: no, it is a physical reader, like http://mobile-solutions.ingenico.com/platform/hardware/rp350x-chip-sign-mobile-card-reader/. This one has an SDK and as I do not have any experience with using SDKs and Cordova I wonder if it is complex to read the data into my phone app.